# How to float the background image to the left side?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have section which I want add a background image placed on the left side

Here is jsfidlle of what I have done so far:

**UPDATED LINK** : http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/4f6xuh8b/39/

Here is the visual of what I want to have.

[image]

```css
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ {
    /* margin-top: 80px; */
    padding: 231px 0px;
    background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/8K7.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 3829px 3581px;
    /* background-position: right; */
    background-position: right;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card {
    width: 536px;
    height: 132px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 41px;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_header p {
    width: 451px;
    height: 184px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #707070;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_header {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.marketing-main-page-content-kontakty-formularz_quote{
    background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/8KX.svg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 937px;
    height: 713px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -432px;
    }
    
    .marketing-main-page-content-kontakty-formularz_quote P {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 70px;
    right: 80px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
 

<div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ">
            <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_header">
                <h5>Faq</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vidit mundi gubergren ne usu, porro evertitur vix et.
.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie">
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">

                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block0" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block0">
                        Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block0" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block2">
                         Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block1" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                       Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block2" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                      Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block3" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                        Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block4" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block5" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                       Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block5" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="marketing-main-page-content-kontakty-formularz_quote">
```

I tried playing with background size but unfortunately I couldn't manage to make it work as expected,

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: did you try this `background-position: left; `?

Comment: @Geek i tried u can see yourself here how it look if u try `left` http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/4f6xuh8b/16/

Comment: you can do  by using `transform: rotate(180deg);` sample demo    http://jsfiddle.net/4f6xuh8b/33/

Comment: @Geek thank you for help but that is completely different to that what I want  :(  please check the visual image for what I want :(

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is closer to what you want. I changed the background size to something that reflects window width.

```
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ {
    padding: 231px 0px;
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/8K7.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150vw;
    background-position: right 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4f6xuh8b/31/)

Easiest way that comes to my mind about not cutting the background with the next div is adding more padding-bottom and pulling it back with -margin. The next background probably won't hit the exact spot you want, but in responsive design is kinda hard to synchronize those two. Feel free to play with those two values.

```
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ {
    padding: 231px 0px 944px;
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/8K7.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150vw;
    background-position: right 0;
    margin-bottom: -713px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4f6xuh8b/45/)

Comment: Yes close to what I want , so if I want the background to go beyond the next div to fit what I want, what do I need to change in you code ? thanks for help

Comment: I'm not really sure that div is on your mind. Do you want to add another div after .marketing-main-page-content-FAQ?

Comment: Yes, I want to have another div u can see in visual image there is left side a small image , and u can see the background image goes beyond its div

Comment: Could you please edit your question so it contains the div you want to add under?

Comment: @mirrous I have added the div to the jsfiddle check it in   my qn

Comment: what about increasing width to right side so that we can have what we want exactly, ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180119/discussion-between-mirous-and-user9964622).