# How to add two background image to the same header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have header with background image, I want the header to have the same background but two times, the effect should look like this.

to get that bottom color I added opacity eg `0.5` to one image, but that opacity affect everything in my header, I want the text and logo not be affected by the opacity of the header banner.

```css
/* Marketing business main header */
.marketing-navbar_items {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.marketing-main-header_banner {
    background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8KR.svg");
    background-size: auto 1199px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center -250px;
    position: relative;
    height: 949px;


}
.sample {
    background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8KR.svg");
    background-size: auto 1199px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center -250px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 949px;
    opacity: 0.5;


}
.marketing-main-header_details {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing-main-header_description p {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: HeaderFont;
    color: white;
    /* width: 55%; */
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 0px;
}

.marketing-main-header_button-primary {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 150px 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #4834D4;
    font-family: Roboto Regular;
    width: 373px;
    height: 92px;

}

.marketing-main-header_button {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid marketing-main-header">
        <div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
        <div class="sample">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto marketing-navbar">
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items  nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class=" marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Faq</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Kompetencje</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>


            <div class="marketing-main-header_details">
                <div class="marketing-main-header_logo">
                    <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/hPrhZp/logo_mib.png">
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-header_title">
                    <h1>SZKOLENIA</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-header_description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an pro dicta maiorum recusabo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-header_sub-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an pro dicta maiorum recusabo.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="marketing-main-header_button">
                    <button type="button" class="marketing-main-header_button-primary">Poznaj Agende</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What do I need to do to get the expected result (text should not be affected by the opacity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `:before` pseudo on `.marketing-navbar_items` like the shown example. This way, it won't affect its child opacity (since it doesn't have any).

```css
/* Marketing business main header */
.marketing-navbar_items {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.marketing-main-header_banner, .marketing-main-header_banner:before {
    background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8KR.svg");
    background-size: auto 1199px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center -250px;
    height: 949px;
}

.marketing-main-header_banner {
    position: relative;
}

.marketing-main-header_banner:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.marketing-main-header_details {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing-main-header_description p {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: HeaderFont;
    color: white;
    /* width: 55%; */
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 0px;
}

.marketing-main-header_button-primary {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 150px 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #4834D4;
    font-family: Roboto Regular;
    width: 373px;
    height: 92px;

}

.marketing-main-header_button {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid marketing-main-header">
        <div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
        <div class="sample">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto marketing-navbar">
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items  nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class=" marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Faq</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
                            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Kompetencje</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>


            <div class="marketing-main-header_details">
                <div class="marketing-main-header_logo">
                    <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/hPrhZp/logo_mib.png">
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-header_title">
                    <h1>SZKOLENIA</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-header_description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an pro dicta maiorum recusabo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-header_sub-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an pro dicta maiorum recusabo.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="marketing-main-header_button">
                    <button type="button" class="marketing-main-header_button-primary">Poznaj Agende</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hii eliya , Thanks for help exactly this is what I needed when it come to opacity and text, very good solution, I have one question why opacity is shown only at the bottom of the header how about left side ? if u can help thanks

Comment: @user9964622 your welcome! as you can see, I pushed down the other part 50px from the top. If you want to push it to the left too, you'll have to add something like `right: 50px`

Comment: yes pushing`top` and `left` i get a white space on left top right side where there is opacity u can check it yoursef on jsfiddle

Comment: update this property: `.marketing-main-header_banner:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: 0.5;
}`

Comment: here is jsfiddle with you solution Eliya : http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/a5e4d7u3/3/ u can see what I mean

Comment: That works perfectly but it adds both side opacity if I want only bottom  and left side , what do I need to change?

Comment: El perfecto , Thank you a lot brother ur the GOAT ,  if you dont mind  u can check this thread of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343031/how-to-float-the-background-image-to-the-left-side